# Haskell - read in graph specification from a file

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to read in (and also how to represent) a graph in Haskell.

The input from the file will look something like

```
NODES 3
EDGE 1 2
EDGE 1 3
EDGE 2 3
```

I have figured out how to grab the individual lines of input from the file using:

```
loadFile :: String -> IO [[String]]
loadFile filename = do 
                contents <- readFile filename
                return $ map words $ lines contents
```

That gives output like:

```
loadFile "input.txt"
[["NODES","3"],["EDGE","1","2"],["EDGE","1","3"],["EDGE","2","3"]]
```

What I really need to figure out is how to represent this graph data as a graph, though.
I was thinking of setting it up as a list of edges:

```
type Edge = (Int,Int)
type Graph = [Edge]
```

But then I'm not sure how I would even begin to implement the functions I need such as addNode, addEdge, getNodes, getEdges.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be awesome!  Note: I can't use any already developed graph modules for this.

So, for the tl;dr version:

1. Am I reading in the data the best way?
2. How should I represent this data in haskell?
3. If I use the data structures I outlined above, how would I go about implementing one of those functions.

Comment: What you have so far looks good. Have you tried implementing any of those functions? What problems did you run into?

Comment: My biggest problem is trying to wrap my head around how to have an item (graph) that I would add something to.  I come from an imperitive language, and in that we would just have a variable of some sort that stays there and is accessible.  How would you even go about this in a functional language.  All I've really had to do so far is write functions that are standalone and just return a value for the things that are input.

Comment: EDIT: tel pretty much answered this question below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of interesting concerns going on here. Let me attack them all.

1. You're reading in the data just fine for a line-oriented language. Later on you'll see `Data.ByteString` and `Data.Text` replace `String` for efficiency. You'll also see `Parsec` for parsing. Those can wait, though. Revisit them in time.
2. Your graph representation is fine. Adjacency lists are a common and useful representation.
3. Now, the real trick you have is here. Let's take a look at `addNode` and `addEdge`. Each is a somewhat challenging function to produce in a pure functional language because they want to *modify* a graph... but we don't have state.

The most important way to modify-without-state is to mutate. The kind of function you're looking for is thus

```
addNode :: Node -> Graph -> Graph
```

where the returned `Graph` is identical to the input `Graph` except with one more edge. You should note immediately that there's something wrong here---adjacency lists assume that there are no orphan nodes. We can't add just a single node to the graph.

There are two solutions. One, we could "link" the node in to the graph (which is really `addEdge` in disguise) or two we could extend the graph representation to include orphan nodes. Let's do (2).

```
data Graph = Graph [Edge] [Int] -- orphans
```

Now let's implement adding an edge. Assume you can have duplicate edges, adding an edge to the adjacency list is easy, just append it

```
addEdge0 :: Edge -> Graph -> Graph
addEdge0 e (Graph adj orph) = Graph (e:adj) orph
```

but that's not good enough---we want our orphan list to only include truly orphaned nodes. We'll filter it.

```
addEdge :: Edge -> Graph -> Graph
addEdge (n1,n2) (Graph adj orph) = 
  Graph ((n1,n2):adj) (filter (/=n1) . filter (/=n2) $ orph)
```

`getEdges` is trivial since we're already storing the list of edges

```
getEdges :: Graph -> [Edge]
getEdges (Graph edges _) = edges
```

`getNodes` just needs to append all of our nodes from the adjacency list to the orphan list. We could use `Data.List.nub` to get only the unique nodes.

```
getNodes :: Graph -> [Int]
getNotes (Graph adj orph) = nub (orph ++ adjNodes adj) where
  adjNodes [] = []
  adjNodes ((n1,n2):rest) = n1 : n2 : adjNodes rest
```

---

Hopefully these give you some indication of how to think in a functional language. You'll hava to dig into them a little bit to see how they work, but I've introduced a large number of interesting concepts here.

Next steps here might include trying to use the `State` monad to recapture imperative state modification and to chain these `Graph`-modifying functions together.

Comment: Wow, thats an awesome answer!  That really hit at the root of my problem...modifying something where we have no state.  But you explained that very nicely! One question, though....I don't quite understand how the graph type you set up works...is it recursive somehow?

Comment: @user677786: The name `Graph` on the right hand side of the `=` is the name of the data constructor, which lives in a different namespace from the type constructor `Graph` on the left. The type is not recursive.

Comment: Another followup question, if you have time!  I'm trying to process the edges from the file, and in the process i found out that there is a very odd side effect of grabbing strings from files....the IO monad follows the result around forever...So while trying to turn the file text into edges, I came up with this: **liftM (map l2edge) $ liftM (map tail) $ liftM  tail  (loadFile "input.txt")**     Is there anyway to get rid of the IO monad, or am I stuck with it like I thought?  Also, is there a cleaner way to do this portion?

Comment: Monadic design is an enormous part of Haskell. You can "escape" temporarily from a monad using `liftM` as you've seen. You can also rebind new `IO` actions using "bind" `(>>=)`. Finally, `do` notation helps immensely for making it easier to read chains of monadic code. It's worth noting, however, that this "side effect" you've discovered is the heart of type-safety in Haskell. It's annoying now, but you'll come to love it.

Comment: So basically until I learn to love it, deal with it and use liftM, and do structures where needed to accomplish what I need?

Comment: And also, will I need to change my data types to handle the IO monad versions of the edges and orphans?

Comment: There are a lot of great books on Haskell and they spend a lot of time on monadic code. [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is a popular intro book. [This chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) is specifically about monads. The short answer is that `liftM` is useful in some circumstances, but `>>=`/`return` and `do` are more general and easier to use. Finally, you'll not need or want to change your structures—`Graph` is pure itself. Examine `wrapEdges :: IO [Edge] -> IO Graph` where `wrapEdges ioe = ioe >>= \edges -> return (Graph edges [])`

Comment: Briefly:  yes, you are stuck with the `IO` monad.  Fortunately, that's the whole point:  the "stuckness" is what lets you do I/O in a pure functional language.  The best way to deal is to avoid the `IO` monad where you can -- writing the algorithmic/datastructure stuff to be as referentially transparent as possible is good design practice anyway...